# Sending NULL in a prepared statement for MySQL doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, mysql, database, networking, database-connection

I'm sending a prepared statement to be executed by MySQL and [it looks like I'm following the protocol correctly](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/prepared-statements.html#com-stmt-execute) but the server always returns:

```
Error 1210 - #HY000 - Incorrect arguments to mysqld_stmt_execute
```

The message bytes are encoded as follows:

```
14 00 00    - size
00          - sequence
17          - message type
01 00 00 00 - statement id
00          - flags
01 00 00 00 - iteration count
80          - NULL bitmap (1000-0000)
01          - new params bound flag    
06 00       - NULL type
03 00       - INT type
0a 00 00 00 - 10 INT value
```

So I can't really understand what's different on this message to what MySQL expects and it doesn't look like I can get MySQL to explain this to me.

The SQL statments sent to the server are:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE timestamps ( id INT NOT NULL, moment TIMESTAMP, primary key (id));
INSERT INTO timestamps (moment, id) VALUES (?, ?);
```

Any help is appreciated on this.

Comment: Dumb question ... JDBC is not good enough for you, or are you writing a new JDBC driver?

Comment: https://github.com/mauricio/postgresql-async/tree/master/mysql-async

Comment: OK, fair enough. At that level I would do a network dump on the connection from a JDBC application and compare the packets. It is not likely you will find a person knowledgeable enough on SE to answer this. Perhaps contact the folk at MariaDB, etc.

Comment: That's what I'm doing now, but if someone else has already done something like this it would be nice. I did get a question answered here the last time.

Comment: Huh, I think I may be able to help..... go figure.

Comment: Your null bitmap is wrong.... should be 01 .... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/prepared-statements.html#null-bitmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your null-bitmap is wrong. Should be 01 and not 80.

[From the doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/prepared-statements.html#null-bitmap):

```
NULL-bitmap-bytes = (num-fields + 7 + offset) / 8
NULL-bitmap-byte = ((field-pos + offset) / 8)
NULL-bitmap-bit  = ((field-pos + offset) % 8)
```

Also from the doc, `For COM_STMT_EXECUTE this offset is 0.`

You have two fields: moment and id.
moment is null.
moment is field index 0.

```
NULL-bitmap-bytes = (num-fields + 7 + offset) / 8
  -> (2 + 7 + 0) / 8
  == 1

NULL-bitmap-byte = ((field-pos + offset) / 8)
  -> ((0 + 0) / 8)
  == 0

NULL-bitmap-bit  = ((field-pos + offset) % 8)
  -> ((0 + 0) % 8)
  == 0
```

Thus, the Null bitmask is 1 byte, and to set the bit for field 0 we do:

```
nulls[byte_pos] |= 1 << bit_pos
```

which in your case is

```
nulls[0] |= 1 << 0;
```

thus nulls[0] is `01`

Comment: ok, let me get this straight, instead of sending `1000-0000` i'm going to send `0000-0001` for this?